# Determine size of char array to convert numbers with the preprocessor

Tags: c, printf, c-preprocessor, microcontroller, c-strings

I'm facing this simple "problem" literally every day and don't yet have a good solution for it:

```c
char text[STRING_LENGTH + 1] = ""; 
int32_t number = -12312313; 
itoa(number, text, 10); //or sprintf(text, "%d", number);
```

How do I determine `STRING_LENGTH` in the preprocessor? `STRING_LENGTH` should be the maximum length, the type to convert could produce. In my case `int32_t` => 11.
Surely, I could do something like this:

```c
#define INT32_STRING_LENGTH 11
#define UINT32_STRING_LENGTH 10
//...
```

but it seems like there should already be a solution to this out there.

It's also an option to use `snprintf` in that case, but that would calculate the length while the application is already running. There's really no need to do this while running (if you have some spare-bytes):

```c
int32_t number = -12312313; 
char text[snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", number) + 1];
snprintf(text, sizeof(text), "%d", number);
```

Maybe there's a solution using `"%d"`, `"%lu"`, ...?

Please correct me, if I'm wrong with anything I mentioned here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you spending so much time worrying about a few CPU cycles **when you don't even know if there would be any performance improvement at all, or even if there were an improvement it would be noticeable**?

Comment: Just put `#define STRING_LENGTH xxxx` where `xxxx` is sufficiently large so `text` can contain any 32 bit number. Be generous, if `STRING_LENGTH` is too big, you waste only some bytes of memory, and if `text` is a local variable you only "waste" some stack space (providing local variables are store on the stack on your platform) which will practically have no impact at all.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Because I want it to be clear. The typical "Ah, should be large enough" is very error prone. If `text` is not just a single number as string, but 10 numbers, 4 strings, etc..., joined together it's really likely to make a mistake. And we all know, that mistake could be fatal in some cases.

Comment: @AndrewHenle It's all about the fact, that this *could* be done by the preprocessor.

Comment: In case `number` could be replaced with a constant, you can do all of this including the conversion at compile-time through the pre-processor.

Comment: @FlorianMoser *It's all about the fact, that this could be done by the preprocessor*  And then the compiler gets your code, creates the array the exact size specified by the preprocessor **and then puts the next variable on the next 16-byte boundary anyway**, so your effort had no effect.  You spend a few hours of effort trying to save a handful of bytes or CPU cycles and in the end saved nothing anyway.  Premature optimization is a waste of time and effort.  Literally.

Comment: @AndrewHenle You didn't get the point of that question, sorry. It's not about getting the exact size of the array. It is not even about optimization at all. And I really don't want you to worry about my time, so I'm gonna end this discussion right here.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah, that's right! Unfortunately, I also have to deal with non constant numbers in my specific case.

Comment: in `snprintf(text, sizeof(name), "%d", number);`  replace `sizeof(name)` to `sizeof(text)`

Comment: Anyway I suspect that the correct best solution is simply to hard code a large enough magic number for string size. You could use stringification macros on `INT32_MAX` and similar but unfortunately those macros seem to involve a parenthesis, so you get a few extra bytes. Which is a non-issue. `char str[128];` is perfectly fine too unless you are coding for some very low end 8-bit MCU.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The GNU Portability Library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/) has an amazing single header `intprops` part which has some amazing code available from [github/coreutils/gnulib/intprops.h](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/intprops.h). The header contains `INT_BUFSIZE_BOUND` and `INT_STRLEN_BOUND`:

```
/* Bound on buffer size needed to represent an integer type or expression T,
   including the terminating null.  T must not be a bit-field expression.  */
#define INT_BUFSIZE_BOUND(t) (INT_STRLEN_BOUND (t) + 1)
```

The documentation with usage example is available in the documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/Integer-Bounds.html :

> INT_BUFSIZE_BOUND (t) is an integer constant expression that is a
> bound on the size of the string representing an integer type or
> expression t in decimal notation, including the terminating null
> character and any leading - character. For example, if
> INT_BUFSIZE_BOUND (int) is 12, any value of type int can be
> represented in 12 bytes or less, including the terminating null. The
> bound is not necessarily tight.
>
> Example usage:
>
> ```
> #include <intprops.h>
> #include <stdio.h>
> int
> int_strlen (int i)
> {
>   char buf[INT_BUFSIZE_BOUND (int)];
>   return sprintf (buf, "%d", i);
> }
> ```

Note that the header is under GNU Lesser General Public License. Remember to copy the header with license and distribute your software with some contribution and license. Then just:

```
int32_t number = -12312313; 
char text[INT_BUFSIZE_BOUND(int32_t)];
// or    [INT_BUFSIZE_BOUND(-12312313)];
sprintf(text, "%"PRId32, number);
```

Note that `%d` may be invalid for `int32_t`. Use standard `PRId32` from `inttypes.h`.

---

The heart of the implementation is this nice function, that can be used to basically calculate log10 of a number as a constant expression:

```
/* Bound on length of the string representing an unsigned integer
   value representable in B bits.  log10 (2.0) < 146/485.  The
   smallest value of B where this bound is not tight is 2621.  */
#define INT_BITS_STRLEN_BOUND(b) (((b) * 146 + 484) / 485)
```

So basically to get maximum buffer size length, get the number of bits for a type, calculate `* 146 + 484) / 485)` of that number of bits, add `+1` for minus sign and add `+1` for zero terminating byte - that's the number of bytes that you need.

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for, thanks a lot!
And ty for the additional infos/hints!

Comment: Re “… calculate `* 146 + 484) / 485)` of the maximum value”: The calculation uses the number of bits, not the maximum value.